# One more Fatal error: gnutls_handshake: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received

Tags: ftps, lftp

All,

After installing the new cert from Comodo in my MS2012 server, my FTPS connections from my RHEL6 server are failing with "gnutls_handshake" error. We moved from Verisign signed to Comodo. I went through the different "set" commands but still unable to connect successfully. Can you please help? Thanks a bunch..

```
lx1234$ lftp
lftp :~> open -u uname ftps://server
Password:
lftp uname@server:~> set ftps:initial-prot ""
lftp uname@server:~> set ftp:ssl-force true
lftp uname@server:~> set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
lftp uname@server:~> set ssl:verify-certificate "yes"
lftp uname@server:~>debug 99999999
ls
    FileCopy(0x15c4e80) enters state INITIAL
FileCopy(0x15c4e80) enters state DO_COPY
---- dns cache hit
---- Connecting to server port 990
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_RSA_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_RSA_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_RSA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_DSS_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_DSS_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_DSS_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_DSS_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_DSS_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_DSS_ARCFOUR_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: DHE_PSK_SHA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: DHE_PSK_SHA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: DHE_PSK_SHA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: DHE_PSK_SHA_ARCFOUR_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_RSA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_DSS_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_DSS_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_DSS_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_ARCFOUR_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_ARCFOUR_MD5
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: PSK_SHA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: PSK_SHA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: PSK_SHA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: PSK_SHA_ARCFOUR_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
GNUTLS: EXT[0x19c5d40]: Sending extension CERT_TYPE
GNUTLS: EXT[0x19c5d40]: Sending extension SAFE_RENEGOTIATION
GNUTLS: HSK[0x19c5d40]: CLIENT HELLO was sent [93 bytes]
GNUTLS: REC[0x19c5d40]: Sending Packet[0] Handshake(22) with length: 93
GNUTLS: REC[0x19c5d40]: Sent Packet[1] Handshake(22) with length: 98
GNUTLS: ASSERT: gnutls_buffers.c:599
GNUTLS: XXX[]: ret: 0 Success.
GNUTLS: XXX2[]: ret: 0 Success.
GNUTLS: ASSERT: gnutls_record.c:921
GNUTLS: ASSERT: gnutls_buffers.c:1032
GNUTLS: ASSERT: gnutls_handshake.c:2700
**** gnutls_handshake: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
---- Closing control socket
ls: Fatal error: gnutls_handshake: A TLS packet with unexpected length was 
received.
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have set up ftp server so that the connection is plain text.

try connecting with `ftp://` like this:

```
$ lftp
lftp :~> open -u uname ftp://server
lftp uname@server:~> set ftp:ssl-force yes
lftp uname@server:~> ls
```